# Error access when I'm trying to make request not from dev environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

So I basically have sharepoint asp.net page and button that does this copy operation

```
System.IO.File.Copy("\\\\server.name\\folder\\folder\\123.txt", Server.MapPath("\\\\WebserverTempFileCopy\\123.txt"), true);
```

The problem is if I do this from development environment it works okay, but if I try to do this from outside 403 FORBIDDEN error pops up, basically it can't reach "\\server.name\folder\folder\123.txt" for some reason and I have no idea why.

Request is made by web server, right? But it has access when I'm trying this from development environment, even if outside user is making request he also has access for that fileserver, so I have no idea where to search for error.

I'm new with asp.net and sharepoint, so maybe this is simple and stupid question, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the main problem was that server administrators gave access to file server to wrong identity that was running different server. It took me some time to figure that out.

But that at first also didn't solve the problem.

I found simple way to run that part of code that makes request to file server as app pool identity.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
              //Code here
                });
```

Comment: Shame on me, I was remember that :) Ok, anyway, it is good that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You probably use IIS server for hosting website. If so, your application working in application pool. Application pool has Identity (user) from its working. The error shows that User, from which IIS pool working now, has no permissions to that file.

Comment: Access was granted to app pool identity, but still same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: have you tried to wrap this piece of code into ```try...catch``` and, if exception occurs inside, write it somwhere. I didnt work with sharepoint too long, but also remember that there some way to explore your sharepoint site logs, have you checked it?

Comment: Yes, "Access to the path '\\server.name\folder\folder...' is denied." I'm very new with sharepoint, and mechanic how web server works with file request like this. But at this point access was granted, maybe there is something else that might need access?

Comment: Try to log current user name when you reading that file. Maybe it somehow using impersonation or like this, so u should ensure that you going to file with correct user which has rights. Because right now your problem still with access to file.

Comment: Already tried that, It returns my current system username, not app pool user or anything else.

Comment: So, it means that it uses impersonation to force using user account to move the file. So. seems that your user have to rights... strange

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my point, it makes no sense. Is there some way to force run code as some specific user?

Comment: Yep, U can use smth like this (just fount in google) https://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/

Comment: Heh, looks a little bit scary, but thx, I will try to use this :)